# Else statement invalid syntax in Bread first search

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

```
from collections import deque


graph = {}
graph["you"] = ["alice","bob","claire"]
graph["bob"] = ["anuj","peggy"]
graph["alice"] = ["peggy"]
graph ["claire"] = ["thom","jonny"]
graph["anuj"] = []
graph ["peggy"] = []
graph ["thom"] = []
graph ["jonny"] = []

search_queue = deque()
search_queue += graph ["you"]
searched = []
def person_is_seller(name):
    return name[-1] =='m'

while search_queue :
    person =search_queue.popleft()
    if  person in searched :
        if person_is_seller(person):
            print(person + "is a mango seller")
        return True
        else:
           search_queue += graph[person]
           searched.append(person)
    return False


search('you')
```

I'm studying algorithms and tried to test the bread first search algo but its giving me errors
I get Else: invalid syntax anything I can do to fix it

I tried indenting and I tried checking for errors in the code

Comment: Your `return True` statement is badly indented.

Comment: Where is the `search` function that you called at the end:`search('you')`

Comment: [Code](https://github.com/Veinin/grokking_algorithms/blob/master/06_breadth-first_search/python/01_breadth-first_search.py) that you   ̶c̶o̶p̶i̶e̶d̶   did wrong?

Comment: You should do `search_queue.extend(graph[person])` instead of `+=`.

Comment:  Duck typing might help you with Bread first search.

Answer (score -1):

Your code has indentations errors within your if statement. `return True` should be indented in the nested if statement. There is no `search` function defined either but that's as far as solving your question of else statement being invalid syntax.

```py
from collections import deque


graph = {}
graph["you"] = ["alice","bob","claire"]
graph["bob"] = ["anuj","peggy"]
graph["alice"] = ["peggy"]
graph ["claire"] = ["thom","jonny"]
graph["anuj"] = []
graph ["peggy"] = []
graph ["thom"] = []
graph ["jonny"] = []

search_queue = deque()
search_queue += graph ["you"]
searched = []
def person_is_seller(name):
    return name[-1] =='m'

while search_queue :
    person =search_queue.popleft()
    if  person in searched :
        if person_is_seller(person):
            print(person + "is a mango seller")
            return True
        else:
           search_queue += graph[person]
           searched.append(person)
    return False


search('you')
```

Comment: now i get return is outside of the function when I indent it inside my nested if statement

Comment: figured it out , everything is supposed to be in a function called search with the argument name def search( name ): and search_queue + = graph[name]